fullPage.js: Page scrolls twice on single scroll event
I'm using fullPage.js to create a website with multiple full-screen sections that scroll between each other. However, I'm encountering an issue where, after scrolling once, the page sometimes scrolls to the next section automatically, even though I haven't performed any further scroll action. This behavior seems to happen randomly and is more noticeable after the first scroll event.
Steps to reproduce:
Implement a basic fullPage.js setup with autoScrolling: true and multiple sections.
Scroll down using the mouse wheel or trackpad to move between sections.
Occasionally, the page automatically scrolls one more section after the initial scroll, even though no additional scroll event was triggered.
My setup:
fullPage.js version: 4.0.29
Browser: Google Chrome (latest version)
Device: Desktop (with mouse and trackpad)
What I have tried:
Adjusting the scrollingSpeed and fitToSectionDelay parameters.
Disabling continuousVertical mode.
Testing on different devices and browsers.
Despite these changes, the issue persists. Is there a way to prevent this additional unwanted scroll, or any specific settings I should adjust to fix this?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/4.0.29/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-cdMjnD4i86qiUIK3pyOMeYKdJ2I0gy0CVZm2AvGuXgMRDFdoIEI2I/x39pZlRsMaI4IEZBJbsNuWVawly1nY/A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullPage">
        <div class="section s1">
            <h1>The first section</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section s2">
            <h1>The second section</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section s3">
            <h1>The third section</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/4.0.29/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-jedW9bHnXiSMKNbXfrEQ1gDCRYO8ewRlWPWPf4Fv1LpUyYB0fphiWlUVSGI2Dvwem1gUk0x1Y+cWs4lCwoEo8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        new fullpage('#fullPage', {
            autoScrolling: true,
            scrollingSpeed: 1000,
            fitToSection: true,
            fitToSectionDelay: 600,
            touchSensitivity: 15,
            continuousVertical: false
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

